# Merge XML Files with Java into one document is just loading the first document

Tags: java, xml, parsing

My code below is not really working and I don't know why

This is **input**

```
/*      
             * input 
             * 
             *  //file 1 
             * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
             * <Test>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *          //many other content!!
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             * </Test>
             * 
             *   ...
             *   
             * *  //file n
             * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
             * <Test>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             * </Test>
             * 
             *
```

and this is **expected output**

```
     *  expected output
     *  
     *  *  //one big file
     * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
     * <Test>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     *      <ReferencePoint>
     *      </ReferencePoint>
     * </Test>           * 
     */
```

This is the **actual output**

(just file 1)

```
 *  //file 1 
             * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
             * <Test>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *          //many other content!!
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             *      <ReferencePoint>
             *      </ReferencePoint>
             * </Test>
```

This is **my code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
         mergeXML();
    } //END of main

    public static void mergeXML(){


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        Document doc2 = null;

        try {       


                db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = db.parse(new File("C:/Users/fx12/Desktop/workspace/CoordinateTester/xmlFiles/eins.xml"));
                doc2 = db.parse(new File("C:/Users/fx12/Desktop/workspace/CoordinateTester/xmlFiles/zwei.xml"));
                NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("Test");

              //  Node nodeArea = (Node) doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("area").item(0), true);
               // Node nodeCity = (Node) doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0), true);
               // ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
              //  ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeCity);

              TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
              Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
              transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  

              DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
              StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
              transformer.transform(source, result); 

              Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/fx12/Desktop/workspace/CoordinateTester/xmlFiles/lol.xml"));
              String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();  
              output.write(xmlOutput);
              output.close();
              System.out.println("Ready");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

So what I'm doing wrong that it's not combining both things?

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You don't do anything with doc2?

Comment: You are not using the doc2

Comment: Okay true story. Do I have to do something with transformer object or something with the nodelist to combine both?

Comment: obviously you need to get all nodes from second document and add them to first

Comment: I'm not getting it ... Can anyone help me?